# React Router V6 nested Routes with i18n

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-i18next, nested-routes

I have a question about React Router V6 nested with i18n.

This is my first multi-language service.

```
const MainPage:React.FC = () => {

  const lang = i18n.language;

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <Routes>
          {/* Main */}
          <Route path={`/`} element={<Home />}>
            <Route path={`${lang}`}>
              <Route path={`service`}>
                <Route path={'slack'} element={<Slack />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
            {/* <Route path={`service/dooray`}element={<Dooray />} /> */}
            {/* <Route path={`contact`} element={<Contact />} /> */}

            {/* <Route path={`app/sign-in`} element={<SignIn />} /> */}
            {/* <Route path={`app/sign-up`} element={<SignUp />} /> */}
            {/* <Route path={`app/mail-code`} element={<MailCode />} /> */}
            {/* <Route path={`app/password/reset`} element={<PwdReset />} /> */}

            {/* <Route path={`policies/privac`} element={<Privacy />} /> */}
            {/* <Route path={`policies/terms`} element={<Terms />} /> */}
          </Route>
          {/* <Route path={`*`} element={<>NOT FOUND</>} /> */}
          {/* test */}
        </Routes>
      </Wrapper>
      <ParentModal />
    </>
```

If I enter localhost:3000/en, there is an error `'This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.'`

How can I fix it..

I want /en => go to english page, /jp => go to japanese page

---

```
const MainPage:React.FC =() => {

...

<Route path={`/`} element={<Home />}>
    <Route path={`/${lang}/*`}>
       <Route path={`service`}>
           <Route path="slack" element={<Slack />} />
       </Route>
    </Route>
</Route>
}
```

```
const Home:React.FC = () => {

 return (
 <>
   ... UI, JSX
   <Outlet />
 </>
 )
}
```

I add a `<Outlet />`. But if I entered '/ko/service/slack', render `<Home />` now

---

```
<Route path={`/`} element={<Home />}>
    <Route path="service">
       <Route path="slack" element={<Slack />} />
       <Route path="dooray" element={<Dooray />} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

nested-routes doesn't work.. :(

Comment: now, I fix my code
``` <Route path={`/`} element={<Home />} />
          <Route path={`/${lang}`} element={<Home><Outlet /></Home>}>
            <Route path={`service`} element={<Outlet />}>
              <Route path={'slack'} element={<Slack />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same useCase (localize react router v6) and came up with the following LangRouter [repository link](https://github.com/react-custom-projects/language-router-v6):

```
const LangRouter = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation(),
    { pathname, search, hash } = useLocation(),
    navigate = useNavigate(),
    availableLocales = ['en', 'ar'],
    defaultLocale = (
      getDefaultLanguage() === 'en' || getDefaultLanguage() === 'ar' ? getDefaultLanguage() : 'en'
    ) as string,
    pathnameLocale = pathname.substring(1, 3).toLowerCase(),
    [locale, setLocale] = useState(defaultLocale),
    loaderTimerRef = useRef<any>(),
    [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    loaderTimerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      clearTimeout(loaderTimerRef.current);
    }, 300);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (availableLocales.includes(pathnameLocale)) {
      updateLocale(pathnameLocale);
    } else if (pathname === '/') {
      updateLocale(defaultLocale);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let lang = defaultLocale;

    if (availableLocales.includes(pathnameLocale)) {
      lang = pathnameLocale;
      setLanguageHandler(lang);
    } else if (pathname === '/') {
      setLanguageHandler(lang);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [locale]);

  const setLanguageHandler = (lang: string) => {
    if (lang === 'en') {
      i18n.changeLanguage('en-US');
    } else {
      i18n.changeLanguage('ar-SA');
    }
  };

  const updateLocale = (newLocale: string) => {
    const newPath = `/${newLocale}` + pathname.substring(3);

    if (locale !== newLocale) {
      if (newPath === `/${newLocale}/` || newPath === `/${newLocale}` || pathname === '/') {
        navigate(getHomePageUrl(newLocale));
      } else {
        navigate(`${newPath}${hash}${search}`);
      }
      setLocale(newLocale);
    } else if (newPath === `/${newLocale}/` || newPath === `/${newLocale}` || pathname === '/') {
      if (isAuthenticated()) {
        navigate(getHomePageUrl(newLocale));
      } else {
        navigate(getLoginPageUrl(newLocale));
      }
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="loader-wrapper">
        <LoadingIcon />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <LocaleContext.Provider value={{ locale, setLocale: updateLocale }}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={`/${locale}`} element={<App />}>
          {publicRoutes.map((el, i) => (
            <Route
              key={i}
              path={el.path(locale)}
              element={
                <PublicRouteGuard
                  restricted={el.restricted}
                  redirect={el.redirect ? el.redirect(locale) : undefined}
                >
                  {el.element}
                </PublicRouteGuard>
              }
            />
          ))}

          {privateRoutes.map((el, i) => (
            <Route
              key={i}
              path={el.path(locale)}
              element={
                el.permissions ? (
                  <RestrictedRouteGuard requiredPermissions={el.permissions}>
                    {el.element}
                  </RestrictedRouteGuard>
                ) : (
                  <PrivateRouteGuard>{el.element}</PrivateRouteGuard>
                )
              }
            >
              {el.children &&
                el.children.map((innerEl, innerI) => (
                  <Route key={innerI} path={innerEl.path(locale)} element={innerEl.element} />
                ))}
            </Route>
          ))}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </LocaleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default LangRouter;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Route with an Outlet that detects the language and assigns it to i18next directly:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
    <Route path=":lang" element={<LanguagePath />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="service/dooray" element={<Dooray />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="app/sign-in" element={<SignIn />
      <Route path="app/sign-up" element={<SignUp />
      <Route path="*" element={<>NOT FOUND</>} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Then inside `LanguagePath.js` you can detect the lang and either set it in `i18n.changeLanguage` or redirect the user if it is missing.

```
export default function LanguagePath() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const { lang } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const curPath = location.pathname;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lang && i18n.resolvedLanguage !== lang) {
      if (i18n.options.fallbackLng.includes(lang)) {
        i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
      } else {
        navigate("/" + i18n.resolvedLanguage + curPath, {replace: true});
      }
    }
  }, [lang]);
  return <Outlet />;
}
```

Now if a user arrives at:

```
/ => /
/contact => /en/contact
/en/contact => /en/contact
/fr/contact => /fr/contact
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The error `'This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.'` means the parent route isn't rendering an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to be rendered into. The route rendering the `Home` component doesn't appear to be rendering an `Outlet`.

## Solution

Update the `Home` component to render an `Outlet`. Note that `Route` components without an `element` prop will render an `Outlet` by default.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      ... home page UI/JSX ...
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
const MainPage:React.FC = () => {
  const lang = i18n.language;

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <Routes>
          {/* Main */}
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
            <Route path={lang}>   // <-- renders Outlet by default
              <Route path="service"> // <-- renders Outlet by default
                <Route path="slack" element={<Slack />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
            ...
          </Route>
          ...
          {/* test */}
        </Routes>
      </Wrapper>
      <ParentModal />
    </>
  );
};
```

### Update

If the `Home` and `Slack` components are separate and independent, then move the `Home` component into an index route and simplify the routing to the `Slack` component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path={`${lang}/service/slack`} element={<Slack />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-nested-routes-with-i18n]

Comment: @Jerry I don't quite understand what you are saying. Are you saying that `Home` is its own page component and shouldn't render with nested route content? Can you clarify?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not good english. The comment I written before 9 minutes ago  is deleted. I mean nested-routes doesn't work. I update my question. '/ko/service/slack' render <Home />

Comment: `<Outlet />`component works like render `<Home/>` and under `<Home />` component render `<Slack />` now. But I don't want render under some component

Comment: @Jerry Ok, so are you saying that you want the `Home` component rendered on path `"/"` and `Slack` component to be rendered on a `"/{lang}/service/slack"` path, both independently?

Comment: Yes ! they work both independently.

Comment: @Jerry Ok, I've updated my answer with a suggested routing configuration.

Comment: May I ask more question about multi-language router?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243706/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-jerry).